# Find file path in windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, io

Is there a way to find a particular file path in windows. For example say I want to find the location of `putty.exe` in my local, is there any way I can get the full file path?
I tried the following code using `apache commons-io` utility , but it is taking a lot of time as there are a lot of files in the local.

```
File dir = new File("C:\\");

String[] extensions = new String[]{"exe"};
IOFileFilter filter = new SuffixFileFilter(extensions, IOCase.INSENSITIVE);

List<File> fileList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, filter, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

System.out.println("file list size "+fileList.size());
for (File file : fileList) {
    if (file.getName().toLowerCase().contains("putty")) {
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
    }
}
```

Is there another faster way?

**Edit** I want to find `putty.exe` in particular.

Comment: For what purpose? If it's in the PATH it will execute, and if it isn't you will have to look all over the disk.

Comment: I have to create a logic to run the exe in local, but I don't know where the file is located. For different users the path may differ. That's why I need to find the file path and then run it.

Comment: That's my point. You don't need to know, if it's on the PATH.

Comment: @EJP Its not on the PATH.

Comment: In this situation you should either ship Putty with your program so that you know where to find it, or make it a prerequisite and share a convention between your users. The best convention I think would be for each user to add Putty to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

No program is ever expected to scan the entire disk looking for a file it needs.

Programs use one of the following techniques:

1. Look at the directories in the PATH environment variable, when looking for an executable
2. Require the user to provide the locations of the files at installation time and store them somewhere known. This could be a `.ini` file stored in the program's home directory; on Windows: the system registry or a User or System environment variable (which ends up in the registry as well).
3. The installer creates a launcher shell script that sets an application-specific environment variable which is read by the program.

There are probably several others I haven't thought of.  The idea is to limit the places the program has to search.

Comment: My code will be ran by many different users.  Each of them won't have the path mentioned anywhere. For example in my local. I have that particular .exe file in downloads, this may differ in other users case. So I don't have a common scenario to find out the file. All I know is the file name.

Comment: Then you have to tell the user to be patient while you search, or ask them to tell you. And when you find it, save the location somewhere fixed that you can always retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

When they installed the executable in a regular fashion, it is on the PATH variable.

```
public static Optional<Path> exePath(String exeName) {
    String pathVar = System.getenv("PATH");
    Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile("%(\\w+)%");
    boolean tryVars = true;
    while (tryVars) {
        tryVars = false;
        Matcher m = varPattern.matcher(pathVar);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            tryVars = true;
            m.appendReplacement(sb, System.getenv(m.group(1)));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        pathVar = sb.toString();
    }
    String[] dirs = pathVar.split("\\s*;\\s*");
    for (String dir : dirs) {
        Path path = Paths.get(dir, exeName);
        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            return Optional.of(path);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

System.out.println(exePath("java.exe"));
```

Probably the var pattern substitution is done automatically (%JAVA_HOME% and such)

Comment: Some exe are not installed. Like putty. When I download it, I directly get a `.exe` file, whose path is not mentioned in `PATH` variable.

Comment: ***Out-of-luck.*** An attempt like `PATH+Putty*\putty.exe`? Adding the Downloads directory? Scanning the entire user's directory tree? ***Probably not.*** I do not believe putty registers some file type - so `Desktop.getDestop.open(file)` would start putty. But then Windows has features. Windows has an optional file indexing and search function. There is **regedit** which just might keep entries for putty, but not all non-Administrators may access it. Maybe someone knows.

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` will run the file only when it knows where the file is. My major problem is that for all users the path might not be same. :(

Comment: That was meant to open some data file whose file type was registered for putty. I know of no such one. Then one could open ones own data file and by that start putty. But putty was a very simple tool the last time I used it (from Simon Tatham?).